# How change fields helptext style django?

Tags: css, django

I want change text color etc of help_text in fields models.

I see in html that there is helptext class:
 `<span class="helptext">Sentenses</span>`
so I try in my css file:

```
.helptext {
        color: #bd512f;
}
```

and it dont do changes.
Is there collision with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by code:

```
.helptext {
        color: #bd512f !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the style that is specified last is applied. Perhaps the styles of your frameworks are loaded later than the one you specified. Also, inline styles like your `<span>` have even more precedence.